# return statement in python

Tags: python, return

I tried to code a program but ran into problem with the return statement.

The following lines of code raised an error message saying that the variable `names` is undefined.

However, I did use the return statement to return `names` and pass it to the main function:

```
def main(names):
    names_in()
    print(names)

# import the record, put it into a list,  pass that list to main().
def names_in():
    infile = open('names.txt','r')
    names = infile.readlines()

    infile.close()

    index = 0
    while index < len(names):
        names[index] = names[index].rstrip('\n')
        index += 1
    return names

main(names)
```

I've written another program before that did the same thing and everything worked fine, so I'm not sure what's wrong here?

Comment: Well, what do you want to do with `def main(names):`? Does it really need an argument here? And maybe you mean `print(names_in())`.

Comment: Off-topic: `names_in` makes me cringe. It could simplify to: `with open('names.txt', 'r') as infile: return [name.rstrip('\n') for name in infile]` and would run faster, as well as more obviously and idiomatically.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I did that because the homework requires us to have that function in our program.

Comment: I'm not against having the function. It's the construction of it (emulating a C-like for loop, slurping a file then modifying the lines after the fact, explicit `close` instead of allowing `with` to do the work reliably/safely). Literally the whole function could be rewritten as two idiomatic lines.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: thank you for your correction, I'm new to programming languages so these tips are very helpful for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
main(names)
```

You are calling your `main` function with a variable name that hasn't been defined yet. The error you're getting should display a line number that points to this line: that will validate this is where the problem is.

```
# 'names' is not defined in this scope
def main(names):
    # Some code
    # 'names' is a variable that is 'in scope' here because it's passed as an 'argument'

# 'names' is not defined in this scope either

# import the record, put it into a list,  pass that list to main().
def names_in():
    infile = open('names.txt','r')
    names = infile.readlines()  # defines 'names' for this scope

    # more code
    return names  # because 'names' is defined it can return it

# 'names' is no longer defined in this scope
main(names)  # This fails because when the compiler tries to resolve 'names' it can't find anything
```

Based on what you're apparently trying to do, you need to modify your `main` function like so:

```
def main():
    print(names_in())
```

And call it like so:

```
main()
```

Note, too, you seem to have some confusion over how code is executed. If I write:

```
def a():
    print("a")

def b():
    print("b")

print("c")
b()
a()
```

It gets translated to something equivalent to:

```
print("c")
print("b")
print("a")
```

The `def` statements get copy-pasted, effectively, into where they are called.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just one more follow-up question. The return statement here only returns whatever stored in variable "names" back to the function names_in() after the function's done with all of the steps right?

Comment: That is correct. But it just returns the value, not the name.

Answer (score 1):

Your `main` function should not take in any parameter. Instead, it should use the return value from `names_in`:

```
def main():
    names = names_in()
    print(names)
```

Later in your code:

```
main()
```